# Proving two recursion sequences converge to L given that a1>b1>0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $ \{a_n\}, \{b_n\}$  be sequences defined by:

$a_1\gt b_1\gt 0 \ ; \quad a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2+b_n^2}{a_n+b_n} \quad,\quad b_{n+1}= \frac{a_n+b_n}{2} \\$

To prove is that both the sequences converge and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n$

I'm pretty lost on this problem. Which approach should i take?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451053/prove-two-dependent-sequences-converge?

Comment: Thank you George

Comment: no problem!....